# How to take DSN backup?

Tags: backup, dsn

Can any one suggest me how to take all the dsn in the system? I need to format the system and i want all the dsn names and connections as a backup.

Answer (score 1):

The system-wide settings are stored in HKLM/SOFTWARE/ODBC.  If all you are after are these settings you could export this branch of the registry.  The per-user DSNs obviously are going to be a problem as they are stored in HKCU and not available to anyone but that user.  Be aware that the passwords are stored encrypted so it will only be of limited use.

Comment: I have in fact done this and used the exported registry keys to load matching DSN values on multiple servers.  So I'll add something to test for example, and when it's been tested and I want to move it to devl and prod I export the whole ODBC key.  I then open it on each of the devl and prod servers and I know they all match.  Passwords work too.